# Flash Player Minimizes, 2 Monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, flash, screen, monitor, youtube

I have to screens. When I watch a flash video on one screen and then interact with the other screen the flash player minimizes itself back to the embedded mode. This happens in chrome and firefox (only 2 I tested). This happens in YouTube and Vimeo,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two separate fixes for firefox and chrome.
First you need to install ghex

```
sudo apt-get install ghex
```

For chrome:

```
sudo ghex /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so
```

For firefox

```
sudo ghex /usr/lib/firefox-addons/plugins/libflashplayer.so
```

The next is the same for both

Now search for _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW and replace it with some other string of the same length, e.g. __ET_ACTIVE_WINDOW.  Restart enjoy!

For chrome:
Disable /libpepflashplayer.so
 in chrome://plugins/